# Global initialization with temporary function object

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

The following code

```
#include <random>
std::mt19937 generator((std::random_device())());
```

compiles just file with clang:

```
$ clang++ -c -std=c++0x test.cpp
```

but fails with gcc:

```
$ g++ -c -std=c++0x test.cpp 
test.cpp:3:47: erro: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

Is that code valid in C++11? Is it a bug in GCC or a extension/bug of Clang?

Comment: Fwiw, this both pukes (in Intellisense, error: cast to type "random_device()" not allowed,  and ")" expected expression) *and* still compiles with VS2012 and the Nov2012-CTP.

Comment: You can enforce constructor calls (instead of the weird type interpretation) by using the new-style constructor syntax: `std::mt19937 generator { std::random_device{} () };`

Comment: Adding *yet another* pair of parentheses also works: `std::mt19937 generator(((std::random_device()))());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gcc is parsing the subexpression `(std::random_device())()` as a cast to the function type `std::random_device()`.  It helps to look at icc's error output, which is slightly more informative than gcc's:

```
source.cpp(6): error: cast to type "std::random_device ()" is not allowed
  std::mt19937 generator((std::random_device())());
                          ^

source.cpp(6): error: expected an expression
  std::mt19937 generator((std::random_device())());
                                                ^
```

The relevant production is 5.4p2:

> *cast-expression*:
>
> - *unary-expression*
> - ( *type-id* ) *cast-expression*

Since an empty pair of parentheses `()` is not a *unary-expression*, this production is unavailable and the compiler should select the production from 5.2p1:

> *postfix-expression*:
>
> - [...]
> - *postfix-expression* ( *expression-list*<sub>*opt*</sub> )
> - [...]

where the *postfix-expression* is `(std::random_device())` and the *expression-list* is omitted.

I've filed http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56239 on gcc bugzilla, and it looks like it should be resolved shortly.

Note that if you are supplying arguments to the `operator()` then the compiler is required by 8.2p2 to parse the expression as a cast, even though it is illegal to cast to a function type (if there are multiple arguments, the argument list is parsed as an *expression* using the comma operator:

```
(std::less<int>())(1, 2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ illegal C-style cast
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ type-id of function type std::less<int>()
                  ^~~~~~ argument of C-style cast
                    ^ comma operator
```

The correct way to write this (other than using C++11 universal initializer syntax) is to add another layer of parentheses, since a *type-id* cannot contain outer parentheses:

```
((std::less<int>()))(1, 2);
```

Comment: So, Clang's success is non-standard behavior? Also, what the type `std::random_device ()` means?

Comment: @lvella clang is correct; the expression is parseable unambiguously by the grammar, so gcc is incorrect to fail to parse it.  The type `std::random_device()` is the function type of a function taking no arguments and returning `std::random_device`.

Comment: I thought that would be `std::random_device (*)()`, and only that.

Comment: @lvella `std::random_device (*)()` is a function *pointer* type.  Function types are difficult to see, and aren't often used, but they're part of the type system e.g. a function pointer type is of the form pointer-to-F where F is a function type.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is problem with the way GCC handles function declarations. Take this example:

```
struct A
{
    bool operator () () { return true; }
};

struct B
{
    B(bool) { }
};

B b((         // This cannot be parsed as a function declaration,
    A()()     // and yet GCC 4.7.2 interprets it as such:
    ));       // "error: 'type name' declared as function returning 
              // a function B b((A()()));"

int main() { }
```

Due to the presence of additional parentheses around `A()()`, the syntactic form `B b(( A()() ));` cannot be parsed as a declaration of a function.

The declaration in your question's example is slightly different:

```
B b(
   (A())()
   );
```

Even in this case, though, `(A())()` cannot be interpreted as the type of a function which returns a function that returns `A` (always in an attempt to consider `b` as a function declaration with an unnamed parameter). So the question is: can it be interpreted as anything else? If so, and if its meaningful in this context, then the compiler should consider to parse the whole expression as the construction of object `b`.

This is probably the fundamental point where GCC and Clang disagree:

```
int main()
{
    (A())(); // OK for Clang, ERROR for GCC
}
```

I do not see how the above could be interpreted as anything else than an attempt to construct a temporary of type `A` and invoke its call operator. It cannot be a function declaration, because if `A` is interpreted as the return type, then the name is missing (and vice versa).

On the other hand, `(A())` is a valid expression for creating a temporary of type `A`, and that temporary supports the call operator (whose return type is the same as the type accepted by `B`'s constructor). Thus, `(A())()` should be a valid expression of type `bool`.

For this reasons, I believe that GCC's parsing is wrong.

Comment: OP wrote `B b ( (A())() );` though.

Comment: @jrok: Huh, you're right actually. So have I discovered an unrelated bug?

Comment: But can't it be parsed as `A()` is a type (function returning `A`), so let's call its default constructor `A()()`?

Comment: @zch the value-initialization syntax `T()` does not allow `T` to be parenthesized.  See section 5.2.3.